# How to avoid TFS Code Reviews dominating my shelveset list

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

When using the *Request Review* feature in VS/TFS a shelveset is created with the proposed changes. This shelveset stays around when the review finishes, both if it is accepted and if it is rejected.

This is all fine but the review shelveset tends to dominate my list of shelvesets making it difficult to find a 'real' shelveset. Deleting the shelveset after the review has finished, seems to be bad as it is linked to the review which is linked to the final changeset.

**So my question is whether there are a way of hiding these review shelvesets?**

We are using Visual Studio and TFS 2015 Update 3. Here is how it looks:

[image: Shelveset list with a lot of Code Reviews]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no way of hiding  these review shelvesets**, unless delete them. However,
 if you have deleted the corresponding `CodeReview_XXXX` shelveset as part of clean up activity at a later date.

Then, users go back to the same code review for some investigation, Code Review details doesn't get displayed.

If you need this feature, suggest you to add a related [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) or vote up for below idea, this is pretty much the same thing...

> **TFS: Code Reviews: Shelveset based: Unable to view any details of a code review if one happens to delete corresponding code review
>   shelveset**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16853590-tfs-code-reviews-shelveset-based-unable-to-view